# readCharacteristic not returning data for custom attributes

Tags: java, android, bluetooth-lowenergy, android-4.4-kitkat

When my code didn't work, I started with the project I found [here](http://developer.android.com/samples/BluetoothLeGatt/index.html) and ran it against our custom bluetooth device on my moto-x. Against the general attributes with profiles, I get data back from the following code:

```
public void readCharacteristic(BluetoothGattCharacteristic characteristic) {
    if (mBluetoothAdapter == null || mBluetoothGatt == null) {
        Log.w(TAG, "BluetoothAdapter not initialized");
        return;
    }
    mBluetoothGatt.readCharacteristic(characteristic);
}
```

which returns data asynchronously in:

```
    public void onCharacteristicRead(BluetoothGatt gatt,
                                     BluetoothGattCharacteristic characteristic,
                                     int status) {
        if (status == BluetoothGatt.GATT_SUCCESS) {
            broadcastUpdate(ACTION_DATA_AVAILABLE, characteristic);
        }
    }
```

This also works if i run this code against a heart rate monitor.

If I run it against one of our custom properties without a default profile, the data never comes back. Ever.

A google search included this: [Cannot read characteristic. Android BLE](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22671473/cannot-read-characteristic-android-ble) but setting up notifications did not solve my problem.

Any advice?

Answer (score 0):

I think the PROPERTY_READ, PROPERTY_WRITE isn't set to enabled in your custom properties.

Check for [BluetoothGattCharacteristic PROPERTIES](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/bluetooth/BluetoothGattCharacteristic.html#PROPERTY_READ) -I didn't realize that need to enable the PROPERTY_WRITE, PROPERTY_READ on the BLE hardware and that wasted a lot of time.

The part where to check the PROPERTY should be something like:

```
if ((characteristic.getProperties() && 
BluetoothGattCharacteristic.PROPERTY_READ)> 0) {
     // toast or log here
      }
```

These enable/disable the app or for that matter any app to connect to the bluetooth low energy device

Refer `servicesListClickListner` on [this page](https://github.com/suzp1984/Light_BLE/blob/master/Light_BLE/ble/src/main/java/org/zpcat/ble/DeviceControlActivity.java)

Comment: Thanks for the advice. I checked and the PROPERTY_READ bit is set.

Comment: did you get to fix it? i am also wondering about what is the problem there

Comment: Nope. Starting to think it's something to do with the device.